# Real time graphing with flot, mysql, php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, flot

I'm trying to draw a real time graph as my mysql table is constantly being inserted with values, like a moving graph referenced from 
http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2009/11/how-to-plot-moving-graphs-using-flot.html
The values actually come from a carbon dioxide sensor which updates the value of the table with *co2* values with positions *id*. I changed her Math.Random to the code below:

```
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM node1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());?>
<?php $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );?>

var j = "<?php echo $row['co2'];?>";
var next = "<?php echo $row['id'];?>";

for (var i = 0; i < this.xscale - 1; i++) 
{  
  this.array[i] = [i,this.array[i+1][1]];  // (x,y)  
}   
this.array[this.xscale - 1] = [this.xscale - 1,j];
```

However, when i run this code, the first value changes, after which it remains constant, even though the last row of the table is being updated.
I heard it is because in php, the server is only polled once. Therefore i only get a constant reading of the first data. Is there any way in which i can make the graph update to the last value of the table? with ajax?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [Periodic refresh (Polling)](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Periodic_Refresh) 
or
[HTTP Streaming](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming).

Note that both of these options can be quite bandwidth demanding.

Comment: Is there a not so bandwidth technique? or is there something i can do to just add on to the preexisting code?

Comment: @Sunny There's a trade-off here, the more "real time" you want it to be, the more bandwidth you are going to use. There's no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do some sort of polling. But even before you do that, 
1. create a php file that retrieves all the important data from the db. 
2. let that file echo/return that data in a formatted way. 
3. have js function poll that file at intervals (a function that runs in setInterval() )

and yes.. there would be some bandwith issues but i think its manageable.